# How do I round a value to 2dp in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to record a value as 2dp but I'm having issues getting it to work.

I have one workbook which holds test cases. The macro takes these test cases and runs them through a separate workbook. The calculated values from the second workbook are then recorded back in the first workbook.

I can get all the values through fine, but want three of them to be 2dp. I can get them to show as 2dp at the moment, but when I click on the cell the actual value is to approx 13dp. How do I get the value to be to 2dp, not just shown as 2dp?

```
Dim MPCalc as Single
MPCalc = Sheets("Calculation").Cells(45,11).Value
MPCalc = WorksheetFunction.Round(MPCalc,2)
Cells(i, MPCalc_Col).Value = MPCalc
```

I've tried .NumberFormat = "0.00", format(MPCalc,"0.00"),Round(MPCalc,2) but they all bring through a 13dp value shown as 2dp and I'm not sure why!

Comment: Where do you wright your values back to your sheet? And also, can you give an example of the three values that won't round to 2dp? Simply formatting a value does **not** change it's actual value, just its representation!

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Just write that value back to the sheet following the calculation. As JvdV pointed out, formatting only changes the appearance i.e. the **formatting**

Comment: @Daghan I've edited my initial post to show where I record the value of MPCalc. I was certain the code should work but it's just not doing what I expected - for example, one instance of MPCalc is 9.012499... and I want this to return 9.01. The values in the watch window all show 9.01, the value shown when I record the value is 9.01, but when I click on the cell it's actually 9.012499... I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: @JvdV see my reply above to Daghan

Comment: @samm well what is `i` and `MPCalc_Col` in `Cells(i, MPCalc_Col)`? probably you are writing not into `Cells(45,11)`? So you are watching the wrong cell? Also you didn't specify in which sheet `Cells(i, MPCalc_Col)` is so you might have written into another sheet.

Comment: @Peh I want to write the value into a different workbook than the one MPCalc is in, and the location in the other workbook is based on the test number row (i) and pasted into the correct column(MPCalc_Col). There's some code in the middle where I activate the workbook I want - I'm pretty sure it's writing into the right workbook because I've deleted the values where I want them recorded and ran the macro again and these are being filled in

Comment: @samm, any luck on this?

Answer (score 3):

After rounding

```
Dim MPCalc As Single
MPCalc = Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(45,11).Value
MPCalc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(MPCalc, 2)
```

the rounded value is in the variable `MPCalc` but not in your cell. Therefore you need to write it back to your cell:

```
Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(45,11).Value = MPCalc
```

---

Alternatively all in one:

```
With Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(45,11)
    .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(.Value, 2)
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively (or adding) to @Peh his answer:

```
Sub RoundRange()

With Worksheets("Calculation")
    .Range("A1:A4").Value = .[ROUND(A1:A4,2)]
End With

End Sub
```

Or more dynamically:

```
With Worksheets("Calculation")
    .Range("A1:A4").Value = Application.Round(.Range("A1:A4"), 2)
End With
```

Instead of `.Range("A1:A4")` you can `Set` another `Range` variable.

Comment: Even better than looping! Nice.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, yes. But now I'd might as well delete my answer. Hehe, just wanted to point out the looping =). Thought it might look intrusive to put it in a comment below your answer. Should I delete?

Comment: No, why delete? I removed the looping from my answer. This is a way faster than looping. I think people will benefit from this answer. You could add a `.Value` to the ranges to make it absolutely clear ;)